# Running Script to Modify Database - Mongoose Model.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a basic script to find all customers without a name field, and log them. The error `Customer.find is not a function` is returned. The rest of the code works just fine when running the app normally, so it is not a module export issue. The customer module works perfectly when running the app normally. I execute this script by calling `node server/scripts/script.js`

Any ideas? Full code and error below.

**Script**

```
'use strict';

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

require('babel-core/register');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/environment');
const Customer = require('../api/customer/customer.model');

mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

console.log('Customer');
console.log(Customer);

Customer.find({
  $or: [
    { 'name': false },
    { 'name': '' },
  ],
}, function (err, customers) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(customers.length);
});
```

**Error**

```
Customer
{ default: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Customer',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        name: 'toro-dev',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 2,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        _listening: false,
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     findScript: [Function: findScript],
     schema: 
      Schema {
        paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [Object],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: [Object],
        statics: [Object],
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [Object],
        s: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: null,
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'customers',
        collectionName: 'customers',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: true,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     insertMany: [Function] } }

Customer.find({
         ^

TypeError: Customer.find is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tori/Documents/RocketSled/toro/server/scripts/remove_empty_customers.js:16:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

**Edit:**
Added console log of `Customer` above so you can see what it is actually linked to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was babel - in the rest of my program, I have babel implemented so that my Customer model can be exported in a certain way. With a one-off script however, babel is not integrated or required as usual, so I had to export the Customer model in accordance with old school ES5 syntax. Changed my customer export to this:

```
export default mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
```

and now it works great. In my typical code, I only use the first line. I hope this helps someone else!